# Will Facebook ads app install work without Facebook SDK Integration in the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sdk, facebook-ads-api

I want to track number of app install via Facebook ads app install. I have registered my app at Facebook Developer(http://developers.facebook.com/), completed App Settings Page and
App Detail Page. 
 
 Will it work without integrating Facebook SDK in the application ??

Do i need to add following code in the Application delegate or not ??

[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:YOUR_APP_ID]; 
[FBAppEvents activateApp];

Can i track the Facebook ads app install without any kind of coding in the application??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Facebook's Ads products and not about programming for Facebook's API

Comment: From the Facebook Ads FAQ page: "To measure installs, you need to register your app and either integrate our SDK or work with a Mobile Measurement Partner."

Answer (score 1):

You can setup ads with an [objective of mobile app installs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/mobile-app-ads/v2.2) without needing app integration via FB's SDKs, yes. Just follow the directions for these ads and set the appropriate call to action and tracking specs accordingly.

But much like the feedback loop of website conversion ads with conversion pixel tracking, to get useful data from mobile app install ads you'll want to have [install reporting from within your app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads#advanced).

Comment: Why can't we just have the ads go to the appropriate app store page without tracking? If we don't need tracking why do we need facebook sdk

Comment: Ads can go to an app store without tracking but implementing the Facebook SDK into your app allows FB to improve and optimize ad delivery, possibly getting you higher better results.

Comment: you are right, I stupidly thought we couldn't even make an app ad without the sdk but I figured out how to do it now